# Roll-Up ou Drill-Down, Qual possui maior Detalhamento em Data Warehouse?

Tags: banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

## Contexto

Estudando sobre data warehouse(DW) me deparei com o conteúdo a respeito do tipos de servidores OLAP e os tipos de operações que podem ser feitas, dentro desse contexto fiquei confuso em relação ao conceito de detalhamento sobre duas operações, são elas chamadas de **Roll-Up** e **Drill-Down**

No livro o autor afirma que a operação de Drill-Down possui maior **detalhamento** porém o exemplo dado não me fez entender bem.

### Exemplificação do Livro.

Capítulo 29 - Visão Geral de Data Warehousing e OLAP.
Segue abaixo como as operações são visualmente exemplificadas pelo autor do livro.

> Exemplo Roll-Up
>
> > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Exemplo Drill-Down
>
> > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### O Que o site Teradatapoint Afirma

Como não ficou muito claro a explicação, fui para o google e encontrei esse [artigo do teradatapoint](http://www.teradatapoint.com/data-warehousing-olap) que me fez entender melhor.

> Sobre a operação de Roll-Up
>
> > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Meu Entendimento

O conteúdo ilustrado no site teradatapoint, me fez entender melhor o assunto e se eu pudesse resumir ou exemplicar em poucas palavras as operações, seria mais ou menos assim:

> Operação de Roll-Up procura **reduzir** o cubo 3D para uma análise mais enxuta, por exemplo: Realizar uma análise bimetral de determinado produto em determinada região.

---

> Operação de Drill-Down procura **aumentar** o cubo 3D, para uma análise com um intervalo de tempo maior , por exemplo realizar análises em intervalos anuais de determinado produto em determinada região.

Entendo por detalhamento dos dados, uma delimitação cada vez menor do escopo envolvido, o que indica diminuição no tamanho da dimensão do cubo, mas o livro afirma o oposto.

## Dúvida

Fiquei sem entender em qual das duas operações existe um maior **detalhamento dos dados**, o livro afirma que é o Drill-Down e o site do terapoint diz que é o Roll-Up.

Fonte: Sistemas de Banco de dados 6ª edição, autores: Elmasri, Ramez Navathe, Shamkant B. Ano: 2011 Cap 29 pg 724 e 725

Answer (score 2):

Bom sou novato por aqui e esta é minha primeira resposta. Como meu conhecimento sobre o assunto também não é dos mais profundos, tentarei ser o mais resumido possível.

**OLAP**

Quando o banco de dados está construído em OLAP, quer dizer que ele não é mais relacional, ou seja não existe aumento ou diminuição na quantidade de dados, eles já estão em um formato cuja recuperação costuma ser mais rápida que em um banco de dados relacional. Porém, existem versões de OLAP, que vão desde ROLAP (com um motor relacional), MOLAP (Com um motor multidimensional) e um intermediário HOLAP (Hybrid). Infelizmente nunca trabalhei com nenhum híbrido para dar maiores explicações.

**Quanto ao Drill-Down e ao Roll-up**

Quando se acessa as informações de um banco de dados OLAP (ou seja, Multidimensional) é possível que ele tenha duas ou mais dimensões. Algumas destas dimensões podem ter hierarquias. As hierarquias mais altas são as informações agregadas das hierarquias mais baixas, por exemplo: Um lado da dimensão pode ser construídos com informações da localização de clientes. Neste caso, Brasil seria a hierarquia mais alta. Ao aplicar um Drill-down, esta hierarquia poderá se dividir de várias formas, como por exemplo regiões (Norte, Sul, Sudeste etc.) ou estados (SP, RJ etc.). Quão mais baixo você desce no detalhamento das informações, mais aumenta a chance de você encontrar células sem medidas da mesma forma que a informação se torna detalhada.

Quanto ao Roll-Up, pode-se pensar na dimensão produto pois fica mais fácil de compreender. Você pode estar organizando o banco de dados de uma loja de varejo com vários produtos. Portanto cada produto seria a célula mais baixa da hierarquia desta dimensão. Desta forma, ao aplicar a agregação das vendas de determinado grupo de produtos (Liquificador -> Produtos de Cozinha -> Eletrodomésticos, por exemplo), a complicação existente neste ponto é o fato de a informação não estar padronizada entre os produtos, por exemplo, o que irá exigir alguma forma de transformação dos dados.

Espero ter respondido. Abraços!